# character falling though ground - faulty custom physics?

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

As a way to learn cocos2d-x 3.x, I am porting various cocos2d-iphone projects to C++.

Found Ray Wenderlich's Mario/Koala tutorial. In addition to porting the existing code to C++, I adopted it for multiple window sizes.

Have a problem, that I don't know how to solve best. Ideas?

The code uses a custom physics engine, checking tiles surrounding the character for collisions once every update interval.
Sometimes, a character falls through tiles. I suspect that it happens because the character is moving fast enough to pass through enough tile to be on the "other" size by the time, the update selector is called.
I am thinking whether this is the case and what should be done:

1. replace physics engine with box2d or something,
2. improve physics engine to keep last coordinate and to check whether it skipped a tile or tiles, and if yes whether a collision should have occurred,
3. tune character speed bounds,
4. something else clever.

Does it make sense that a simple collision detection system, checking only for collisions with surrounding tiles, could allow objects slip thru barriers?

Thank you

Comment: How about you do collision detection on the entire trajectory line segment rather than on the final position?

Comment: thank you. you are suggesting number 2 then?